# Couch db views without total rows

Tags: php, view, couchdb

im trying to create a view

```
 "total_rows": 3,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [{
        "id":"64ACF01B05F53ACFEC48C062A5D01D89",
        "key": null,
        "value": {
          "LastName":"Katz",
          "FirstName":"Damien",
          "Address":"2407 Sawyer drive, Charlotte NC",
          "Phone":012555754211
        }
      }
```

**It works fine, i am doing 
echo json_encode with it...but i need to remove 
"total rows","offset" and "rows" so it can look like this**

```
"id":"64ACF01B05F53ACFEC48C062A5D01D89",
        "key": null,
        "value": {
          "LastName":"Katz",
          "FirstName":"Damien",
          "Address":"2407 Sawyer drive, Charlotte NC",
          "Phone":012555754211
```

.
is there a way? some option in php or in the same view options.
Thanks

**I am creating the view in this way**

```
$response = $client->getView('all','by_date');
```